# Virtual PC 64-bit ntoskrnl.exe

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I had a 32-bit windows 7 box running Virtual PC, with a Windows 2003 guest.  It performed flawlessly.

I recently put in a 64-bit Windows 7 box.  I installed 64-bit Virtual PC.  I copied the VHD file from my old box, to the new one, and I get:

```
Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt: 
<Windows root>\system32\ntoskrnl.exe. 
Please re-install a copy of the above file
```

I had a coworker copy the file off my old machine and set up a Virtual Machine using the same VHD file, and he got a logon screen.

I've tried repairing the file using WinImage.  I've tried Virtual Box (guest threw a blue screen).  I've tried reinstalling everything fresh.  It's obviously something to do with the 64-bit architecture, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Comment: Are all Virtual PC and VM settings the same between the two computers? Specifically those regarding hardware virtualisation.

Comment: whatis the machine you were running the virtual box on?

Comment: Everything seems to match (but I need to double check the BIOS).  The box is runs on fine was a 32-bit Windows 7 Acer with 4 GB RAM.  The box I can't get the VHD running on is a 64-bit Windows 7 Acer with 8 GB ram.  Same "family", if you will.